# Add single file to PHP open_basedir paths?

Tags: php

Is it valid to add a single filepath (not a directory/folder) to the `open_basedir` config in PHP?

Is this valid:

```
/var/log/apache2/php.log
```

Or MUST it be

```
/var/log/apache2/
```

Comment: The [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) don't really say. They seem to assume that everything listed in open_basedir will be a directory. Sounds like the sort of thing that may work if you try it.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman it's exactly that. The docs make me assume it would not work but it actually does, I tried it on staging server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the docs saying the parameters are seperated directories, it works also with specific files.

Example:

```
open_basedir = /var/log/apache2/php.log
```

You can write now to the file `php.log`, **but**, you can't work on the directory `/var/log/apache2`.

Comment: Sweet! Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

Per the PHP [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) - only directories are supported.

> Limit the files that can be accessed by PHP to the specified directory-tree, including the file itself.